# Git Archive ZIP Specified Files/Folders

Tags: git, git-archive

I am trying to use `git archive` to archive only the files I specify and I am getting `fatal: Not a valid object name` error. Could someone provide an example?

My current code:

`git archive -o ./archive/archive.zip ./folder1 ./folder2`

The result should be an archive.zip file with folder1 and folder2 as the sub directories.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a commit or tree to archive, e.g.:

```
git archive -o ./archive/archive.zip master folder1 folder2
```

or:

```
git archive -o ./archive/archive.zip HEAD folder1 folder2
```